# Allow Dropbox to finish uploading even if file is editted

Tags: dropbox, upload

I have a text file in Dropbox in which a new line is added every 10 seconds. Normally, this is enough time for Dropbox to finish uploading the file before a new edit is made, but every once and awhile, it seems that Dropbox gets stuck in a cycle of trying to upload but having the file update before uploading is complete. Is there a way to have Dropbox finish uploading the old version before trying to start uploading the latest version?

Working on a Windows Vista machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the design of Dropbox and your slow upload speed. You can try splitting up your text file into different names and that will make it easier to upload files in smaller parts.

Comment: Do you know if it re-uploads the whole file every time? Or if it just uploads differences? Something akin to how GitHub stores files and difference.

Comment: I believe Dropbox hash files in 4MB pieces. If your text is smaller than 4MB, it may re-upload the entire file. If the file is bigger than 4MB, Dropbox will upload part of the file only. Yes, Dropbox has previous versions which I suppose is similar in concept to GitHub's version control.